# Refreshing DOM so Selenium Web Driver can find element

Tags: python, selenium, dom, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium's Chrome web driver to navigate to a page and then fill out a form. The problem is that the page loads and then 5 seconds later displays the form. So JavaScript changes the DOM after 5 seconds. I think this means that the form's html id doesn't exist in the source code the web driver receives.

This is what the form looks like with Chrome's inspect feature:
[image: page element]

However that html doesn't appear in the page's source html.

Python used to find the element:

```
answerBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='answer0problem2']")
```

How would I access the input field within this form?

Is there a way to refresh the web driver without changing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into this problem because you didn't give the website enough time to load.

use `time.sleep()` like this:

```
import time
driver.get('http://your.website.com')
time.sleep(15)

plain_text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
```

This works because selenium spawns it's own process and is not affected by the python `sleep`. During this sleep time the headless browser keeps working and loads the website.

It's helpful to implement a `sleep` time for each selenium executions to account for page load. Because the only way the python process communicate to selenium is when you call `driver`, calling before page load can have consequences like the one you described.

Comment: Thank you, I tried 10 seconds, but I guess it wasn't enough. *derp*

Comment: There are more option you can use it the website is actively filtering for scrapes, e.g. by setting `DesiredCapabilities['pageLoadStrategy'] = none` will return you real time load result without waiting for the page load to actually finish. And some website will simply not allow page load to finish to prevent scrapes.

Comment: Bad advice. `time.sleep` is not a solution, and should never be used. A right way is to add explicit wait pattern, e.g. `wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15)` and replace `find_element_by_xpath` with  and `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH` etc

Comment: @KirilS. I tried but `WebDriverWait` does not stop the process and `driver.page_source` runs immediately after and returns nothing - Is there anything needed on the python side to make it  return value *after* the wait if I intend to use `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: what are you waiting for? and how your code looks like?